# SpringMVC + JPA + Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, entitymanager, persistence.xml

I am getting the " Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence' exception.
I tried the solution given at [OpenJPA 2.1.1 - Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311963/openjpa-2-1-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-persistence) but it did not work. Below are the details of my project. I have tried updating the 'persistence.xml' based on other solutions posted on StackOverflow, but no luck.

**Project structure** :

[image]

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="DerbyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/SpringPrac</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.example.dto.Vehicle</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Transaction integration -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.cts.interceptor.AuditLogInterceptor" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller, com.example.dto" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Creates a EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DerbyPU" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/SpringPrac" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**Tomcat's (apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1) context.xml**

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <Resource name="java:/SpringPrac" auth="Container" username="app" password="app"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
          url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db;create=true" JtaManaged="true"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml, classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</param-value>  
   </context-param>  

   <listener>
   <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 

</web-app>
```

**dispatcherServlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:annotation-config/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller, com.example.dto"/>
</beans>
```

**VehicleEntity.java**

```
package com.example.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicle")
public class VehicleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int vehicleId;
    String vehicleName;

    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }

    public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }

}
```

**VehicleController.java**

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.dto.VehicleCRUD;
import com.example.dto.VehicleEntity;

@Controller
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleCRUD vehicleCrud;


    @RequestMapping(value="/createVehicle.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createVehicle(@RequestParam("vehicleName") String name) {
        VehicleEntity vehicleEntity = new VehicleEntity();
        vehicleEntity.setVehicleName(name);
        vehicleCrud.saveVehicle(vehicleEntity);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("vehicleCreated");
        return modelAndView;
    }

        }
```

**VehicleCRUD.java**

```
package com.example.dto;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class VehicleCRUD {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="DerbyPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveVehicle(VehicleEntity vehicleEntity) {
        entityManager.persist(vehicleEntity);

    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="createVehicle.htm" method="POST"> 
    Vehicle Name : <input type="text" name="vehicleName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**VehicleCreated.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vehicle Created!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Maven Dependencies**

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springHibernate.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateSpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>HibernateSpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>HibernateSpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Spring must not load the `persistence.xml` remove it from the list of files to load. Another thing you are mixing versions of a framework never do that. You are mixing Spring 3.2.4, 3.1.4 and 4.0.7 if you want strange issues that is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, changing all the spring versions to '3.1.4' has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

changing all the spring versions to '3.1.4' has solved the issue. The versions should not be mixed.

[image]